# How do I communicate between different Silverlight user controls and sub-pages?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have 2 user controls on my Silverlight page.  One contains a color picker (i.e. just some rectangles with colors in them and some code behind) and the other contains a listbox displaying items in the color selected in the color picker - or at least that's the idea.  So far I have:

```
UI.MainPage mp = (UI.MainPage)App.Current.RootVisual;
```

from which I can get to the list box:

`mp.ucPenStyles.lstPenStyles`

but what to do next I don't know.  I want the colors of the items in the listbox wo update when a new item is selected in the color picker.  The lstbox is populated from a collection via a method in the listbox user control code behind but I don't know how to access it.

---

Ok, I've thought a bit more about this.  Both my user controls det properties in a separate static class.  User contol A set a property in the clas which user control B must be able to detect has changed and update itself accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to communicate between multiple Silverlight user controls on a single page using  Local Connections quite easily.  This requires Silverlight 3.0 or later.

http://geekswithblogs.net/PeterTweed/archive/2009/07/26/inter-silverlight-application-communication-in-silverlight-3.aspx has a good write-up on how to implement this feature.

Comment: this article is about communication between 2 different Silverlight controls on a web page, not between user controls in a single Silverlight application.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your original question, just that you "have 2 user controls on (your) page".  Local Communications should still work, I believe, but there may be easier ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing components using Prism for Silverlight, you can use the [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)  to send events between decoupled components.

Or, for a more simple application, you can expose a normal event from one of your controls and listen to it from the other control.

Comment: how do I expose a normal event from one of my controls and listen to it from the other control? - this sounds useful

Comment: @defscf sorry, missed the comment. This [link](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/198541/462711.aspx) has an example with a button click. You can change the event to use: public event EventHandler<[your event args here]> OnColourChanged; and then attach to that event in the other control.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits your requirements, but one or both controls can have a public static object that you can use to communicate via.